# Android SDK - Install system image packages offline

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3, android-virtual-device

due to IT restrictions I cannot use to package-install-automation of the Android SDK.

To be able to create an emulator in Androids' AVD manager, I first of all need a system image for my target device.
But regarding the below screenshot I haven't installed any.

So can anyone tell me:
1. where to get an system image for Android 6.0 API Level 23
2. how to install this system image **manually/offline**

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 35):

Firstly select the system image to be downloaded in android studio sdk, then it will start downloading the image and will say `Downloading from <url>`. Copy that URL and download from some download manager like IDM and after downloading, extract the files in system-images folder.

The directory structure pattern is `sdk-folder/system-images/android-<api_number>/google_apis/x86 (or armeabi-v7a)`.

So, extract in correct pattern and then open the android studio sdk, you will see that the package is installed.

Now, you can make a virtual device from the downloaded system image.

Comment: for android 25 playstore images, path will be Sdk\system-images\android-25\google_apis_playstore\x86

Comment: for me I found the correct path was `sdk-folder/system-images/android-<api_number>/default/x86`, in other words it is `default` rather than `google_apis`, I am not sure why

Comment: @Kidburla maybe there are some changes in the current sdk version. You need to confirm with someone who is using latest SDK.

Comment: @AstitvaSrivastava actually I am on a very old SDK version (release 15), so probably it's the other way around

Comment: @Kidburla Yeah, then no need to change the answer it seems.

Comment: C:\Users\shenawy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images

Answer (score 6):

SDK manager does not work for you?
In any case, there are several sites which can be used to download Android SDK system images:

https://web.archive.org/web/20191210131925/http://ady.my/viewer/system-image/

http://www.hariadi.org/android/manual-download-of-android-sdk-components/

Or alternatively **Hard way** :
for Windows, using the SDK Manager,
First make sure you have download caches enabled,then fetch/reload the packages. Then go to My Computer and open folder **.android:** =>
C:/Users/your_username/.android/
(Make sure you have enabled "show hidden files" option)
In there try to locate several xml file in `cache` dir. Those xml files contains URLs and other data of all the sdk package. Every package available in sdk manager can be downloaded through appropriate URL from there.
Open XMLs in IE and try to find what you need. Then you can use URLs from there and you're good to go.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

For those with difficulty in finding the correct path to install. The path will depend whether the image is a playstore image or not.

You can figure out by looking at the images download link:

If the download link is inside the folder **google_apis**, e.g:

```
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/<api-file-name>.zip
```

Your folder structure should look like:

```
sdk-folder/system-images/android-<api_number>/google_apis/
```

But if the download link is inside the folder **google_apis_playstore**, e.g:

```
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/<api-file-name>.zip
```

Then your folder structure should look like:

```
sdk-folder/system-images/android-<api_number>/google_apis_playstore/
```

Answer (score 2):

you can follow [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-4-4-kitkat-installation-instructions-manually) link for manually installing the System Images for emulator, i just installed Android 6.0 (sysimg_x86-23_03) so that i can still render Marshmallow layouts in Eclipse.

These are the sites from where you can download them offline. 
Mostly you will require Intel x86 System image or Intel x86_64.

[First](https://afterroot.wordpress.com/2016/01/01/android-sdk-android-6-0-package-direct-links/), but on this site every version of System image is most recent so you can download :

Intel x86-23_r0X from [here](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sysimg_x86-23_r03.zip) (Revisions are from 03 to 09)

Intel x86_64-23_r0X from [here](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sysimg_x86_64-23_r03.zip) (again, Revisions are from 03 to 09))

Hope i helped those who are looking for solution for older Intel System Images for Android 6.0.

Comment: how to I get the latest android 7

Comment: For android studio or elcipse? you can get it throguh sdk manager.!!

Comment: I did this and system image is not available yet :(

Comment: Images for which version ?