# Install Components inside Android SDK manager externally?

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

Is there any way to install Packages/Components inside Android SDK Manager Externally?

Problem is that if something is downloading and there is interruption in downloading, the download fails.

So is it possible to download the components (like Google Play Services, SDK Platform etc) from website and then install it?

If possible then how to install it. Please Explain.

Answer (score 0):

SDK Manager can be really troublesome,  if a quite fast(1-2 MB/s) network is not available. It actually downloads the links of all sdk-package when you first open it *or* reload the packages. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36503572/2952723).